# Mesolimbic pathway

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neuroanatomy

I am trying to gain a better understanding of the etymology of terms used in neuroscience as that helps me remember things. In this case I am trying to understand the phrase "mesolimbic pathway".

My understanding is the mesolimbic dopamine pathway includes projections from the ventral tegmental area (VTA) in the brainstem to the nucleus accumbens in the ventral striatum.

Questions:

1. Is it called the mesolimbic pathway as it projects from the mesencephalon (i.e. midbrain) to the limbic region of the brain?
2. Is the nucleus accumbans usually considered part of the limbic system?
3. Is the projection from the VTA to the nucleus accumbans considered part of the "mesolimbic pathway" as the outer region of the nucleus accumbens forms part of the amygdala, hence part of the limbic system?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Hi and welcome! "Meso" is Greek for "middle" and it is used because the pathway originates from the VTA of the midbrain. I trust you can answer all of your questions by consulting with the related Wiki articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopaminergic_pathways#Pathways, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesolimbic_pathway.

Comment: @vkehayas Thank you for your reply. I must admit I don't find your comment overly helpful nor does it make me feel particularly welcome at this forum when someone says you can just work it out yourself by reading several links. I had read these links prior to posting my question here and it did not fully clear up my confusion. If my queries were answered by those links I would not have posted here. I would really appreciate it if you (or someone else) could flesh out short answers to my questions rather than just posting links and say work it out yourself.

Comment: My comment was not meant as a reprimand. I found answers to all three of your questions by reading through those links so I do not see the point in pasting quotes from them as an answer. For example, the first question is answered in the first link: "[...] from the ventral tegmental area (VTA), which is located in the midbrain [...] The "meso" prefix in the word "mesolimbic" refers to the midbrain".

Comment: If you still have unanswered questions after you read those links please let us know what remains unclear.  Please keep in mind that on StackExchange sites we expect you to show us your prior work when posting a question, otherwise face the risk of your question getting closed or downvoted. You should take my comments as an opportunity to improve the question or answer it yourself.